# Nodejs app on AWS EB using serverless framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bower

I am setting up a project on AWS. I am using serverless framework for my REST API - so I am using dynamoDB, lambda functions, and gateway api to link everything up on the backend. That all works in a nodejs project locally on my machine. Now I am using elastic beanstalk to upload my project. But it keeps saying I have a bad gateway. I am not sure how to call to server.js to get my project set up. When I first upload files using the console, the project immediately gets downloaded in health.

> Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more
> information, see troubleshooting documentation.
>
> Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.

I can only assume because I need to run npm install, bower install and run my server.js so it continually runs once browser is closed, but the instructions in this video don't really tell me how to set that up:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhc1boyBkJw&t=217s
Can someone point me in the right direction to get all of the parts of my project running on aws?
Edit: I have added the following code:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs: 
    NodeCommand: "node server.js"
    ProxyServer: apache
    GzipCompression: true
```

Trying to see if this will start my project. But wondering if I can add multiple node commands under NodeCommand in order to also install npm and bower.

Answer (score 1):

Bud serverless deploys itself, there is no need to use elastic beanstalk, you just need to run `serverless deploy -v` for the application to deploy (you need your AWS creds and IAM user sorted first as described [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/)).

[Codestar](https://aws.amazon.com/codestar/) is a far more useful tool for CI/CD'ing serverless.